# Hiding fields a form in via CSS

Tags: css, html

So I am trying to hide some of the fields in a form. The input type="" section is fairly easy to hide via ID, however I can't get around to how can I edit the label class.

I did try the :nth-child() selector after reading a couple of posts and sites but can't seem to get it working. Here's what I did. Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong and how I can improve?:

CSS

```
#fc-calc-result-wraps:nth-child(2n) {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="fc-calc-result-wraps" style="display: block;">
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Total At Retirement:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edFV" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Contributions:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edNumPmts" maxlength="3" size="16" disabled="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
     <label class="control-label">Total Invested:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edTotalInvested" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">Interest Earned:</label>
    <input type="text" class="control num" id="edInterest" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group tail">
    <label class="control-label">Last Deposit Date:</label>
<input type="text" class="control num" id="edFVDate" maxlength="14" size="16" disabled="">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which fields do you want to hide?

Comment: WPSE is good for questions that are specific to WordPress development issues. Generic HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions are better suitable for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Please read [the topics here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to know how to ask a good question in WPSE.

Comment: @kero Would like to hide "Contribution"

Answer (score 1):

nth-child depends on the element itself, not the children of an element. So the following CSS means: "Hide an element with the class input-group if it is the second child of an element with the class fc-calc-result-wraps".

```
.fc-calc-result-wraps > .input-group:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```